# Nested table not displaying in IE7

Tags: css, html, html-table, cross-browser

I have a nested table inside a table which is `nestedTable` and it does not show up in IE7 even though it exists in the html and display is not none. Below is my html which seems to be valid and working in Firefox, Chrome and IE8:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead> ... </thead>
   <tbody class="myTbody1">
    <tr class="details">
     <td>
       <table id="nestedTable">
        <thead> 
         <tr>
          <th> Col1 </th>     
          <th> Col2 </th>     
         </tr>
        </thead>    
        <tbody class="head">    
         <tr class="nestedRow">              
          <td> Data</td>      
          <td> Data</td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody class="myTbody2">..</tbody>
  <tbody class="myTbody3">..</tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: At the bottom I see `<tbody class="myTbody2">`. This doesn't look valid. You need to close them

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add in the question. please check edited

Comment: I just checked in the developer tools in IE, it does not add end tag for that `tbody` even though it's in the code. It does the same in ie8 but ie8 displays the nested table.

Comment: Phew! I figured out finally it should be enclosed in a tbody say `nestedTbody`